# Whenever I enter amount more than 500 the program stops! How to fix it?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that runs until and unless the total transaction limit is Rs. 1000. But it stops if you enter 600 or 500 + 300 (sequentially) and so on. How to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  
{

    int limit=1000, trans=0, cash;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the  amount of cash");
        scanf("%d", &cash);

        if(limit>=trans+cash)
            {
                printf("Transaction Successful of Rs. %d\n", cash);
                trans=trans+cash;

            }
        else
            {
                printf("Transaction overlimit!\n");

            }
    }
    while(limit>=trans+cash);

    printf("Total Transaction: Rs. %d\n", trans);

}
```

Comment: I recommend https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: As a side note, once your question is answered it's good practice to mark the answer which helped you most as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

By the time you reach this line

```
while(limit>=trans+cash);
```

you have already added `cash` to `trans`. So in your first example, both variables have the value of 600, and their sum 1200 exceeds 1000, getting you out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to `while(limit>trans)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your last test `while(limit>=trans+cash)` in the case of a successful transaction, `trans` has been modified so you test against old value of `trans` + twice value of `cash`.

I didn't understand when you would like to terminate, I understand that it is possible to continue while it is possible to give cash, but what do you want to do if the given cash (plus the current transaction amount) exceed 1000?

Anyway, something like this may helps you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int limit=1000, trans=0, cash;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the  amount of cash");
        scanf("%d", &cash);

        if(limit>=trans+cash)
            {
                printf("Transaction Successful of Rs. %d\n", cash);
                trans=trans+cash;    
            }
        else
            {
                printf("Transaction overlimit!\n");
                break; // get out the loop if over limit.
            }
    }
    while(limit>=trans); // continue if under limit 
    printf("Total Transaction: Rs. %d\n", trans);    
}
```

Comment: Note that `while(limit>=trans)` is effectively dead code: the condition cannot possibly be false.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev since OP didn't provide a good spec, I slightly modify his code to something working and not so far from it.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev thanks a lot, yes i was just adding the value of cash twice, since trans already has the value in it. I have update it to `while(limit>trans)`, removed the equal sign since after 1000 it will run the loop once more(didn't want that!). 

Yes I am also confused what should i do after given cash + current transaction amount exceeds 1000. I want the program to run till the user itself quits (like do you want to exit? y/n command) and prints you can still cash out `limit-trans` amount. How should i do that?